How to create an associative array from grep result?
I have the following data that my grep command gives:
$ grep match data.txt
match key1 value1
match key2 value2
match key3 value3

I'd like to have an associative array that is the equivalent of: declare -A map=( ["key1"]="value1" ["key2"]="value2" ["key3"]="value3").
I managed to extract the key and value using awk e.g:
$ grep match data.txt | awk '{print $2}'
key1
key2
key3

I tried to populate the associative array, but I don't know what the syntax is:
$ declare -A map
$ grep match data.txt | map[$(awk '{print $2}')]=$(awk '{print $3}') # doesn't work


You need to read the output of grep in a loop.

$(awk '{print $2}')) returns all the keys as a single string.  And it consumes all of standard input, so there's nothing for the second awk to read.

while read ignore key value; do map["$key"]="$value"; done <<(grep match data.txt)

Sorry, << should be just <, as shown in the linked question.

I deleted my comment, because it actually worked. Thanks a lot!

<< and < < actually both work, while < doesn't.

Right. Just follow do what it says in the linked question, I'm confusing myself.
